# mostrar usuário pela matricula informada Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Olá, gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês, pois não trabalho na área, mas gosto muito de aprender, comecei a mexer com o codeigniter, estou fazendo um sistema para o pessoal do meu trabalho, hoje é tudo feito no excel. 
O sistema é para gerenciar associados, eu tenho uma tabela de matriculas e nome de todos os funcionários; O meu problema está sendo quando digito a matricula não consigo puxar o nome da pessoa.

Na minha view eu tenho:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
    <label>Matrícula</label>
    <input style="text-transform:uppercase" class="form-control" type="text" id="matricula" name="matricula" placeholder="Nº matrícula"/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input style="text-transform:uppercase"  class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite a matricula" required/>
</div>
```

No final da minha view tem o script com uma solicitação AJAX

```
$("input[name='matricula']").blur(function()
{

    event.preventDefault();
    /*
    var matricula = $('#matricula').val();
    */
    var nome = $("input[name='nome']");
    nome.val('Carregando...');

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl+ 'gesind/pesquisa_mat',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            matricula: $('#matricula').val()
        },

        success: function(){
            var nome = data['matricula'];
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("erro");  
        }

    });

});
```

No meu controller tenho

```
public function pesquisa_mat()
    {

        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
        { 
            exit('no valid req.'); 
        }
        $usr['matricula'] = $this->input->post('matricula');

        $this->load->model("gesind_model");
        $result = $this->gesind_model->pesquisa_matricula($usr);
        if($result)
        {
            echo $result;
        }
        else
        {
            echo false;
        }

}
```

e no Model tenho o seguinte código

```
public function pesquisa_matricula($usr) //checks ajax requests
{   
    $this->db->where('matricula',$usr);
    $query=$this->db->get("matriculas");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue abaixo o código

No Model, estamos selecionando tudo da tabela `matriculas` onde a coluna `matricula` é igual a um parâmetro que estamos passando para a função. O método vai retornar `FALSE` caso não encontre ao menos uma correspondência no db, caso contrário ele retorna a primeira linha encontrada (Estou assumindo que só existe um nome por matrícula)

```
public function pesquisa_matricula($matricula) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('matricula',$matricula);
    $query = $this->db->get('matriculas');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Já no seu Controller estamos pegando o valor enviado pelo pedido ajax e colocando dentro da variável `$matricula` e enviamos esse valor para nossa Model pesquisar no db. Para o retorno dos dados usei a classe de output. Nela estamos dizendo que vamos retornar um JSON e construindo o mesmo. O JSON tem 3 campos

1. dados - Contem o nome do usuário retornado do Model
2. erro - Informa se ouve algum erro na consulta
3. merro - Mensagem do erro ocorrido

Essa forma de retornar os dados facilita no front-end.

```
public function pesquisa_mat()  {
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('no valid req.');
    }
    $matricula = $this->input->post('matricula');

    $this->load->model("gesind_model");
    $result = $this->gesind_model->pesquisa_matricula($matricula);
    if($result) {
        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array( 'dados' => $result->nome,
                                        'erro'  => FALSE,
                                        'merro'   => ''
        )));
    }
    else {
        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array( 'dados' => '',
                                        'erro'  => TRUE,
                                        'merro'   => 'Usuário não encontrado'
        )));
    }
}
```

O Javascript para fazer essa solicitação segue abaixo. Note estamos testando na função de callback se o meu retorno existe algum erro e mostra as devidas mensagem para o usuário. Se a pesquisa não retornou nenhum erro o script pega o valor retornado e joga dentro do campo `nome` do formulário.

```
$("input[name='matricula']").blur(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var matricula = $('#matricula').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl+ 'gesind/pesquisa_mat',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            matricula: $('#matricula').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.erro) {
                $('#nome').val(data.dados);
                alert(data.merro);
            }else{
                $('#nome').val(data.dados);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("erro");
        }
    });
});
```

Para conferir tudo criei a tabela e está tudo funcionando conforme esperado. Caso continue dando erro deixe um comentário para tentarmos resolver.

Comment: Me perdoe Phelipe, mas não consegui, o TRUE quando eu debugo cai no  else
    {
      echo "true";
    } do controller
Se eu colocar var_dump($usr);
  die(); 
no Model ele mostra NULL

Comment: você já debugou e testou se a matrícula está chegando corretamente no seu controller?

Comment: $usr=$this->input->post('matricula');
  var_dump($usr);
  die();

o retorno é NULL, então o meu problema está antes de chegar no controller, correto?

Comment: Exatamente. Mas as modificações que apontem são necessárias. Veja na aba de desenvolvedor o que está voltando. Só ir na cessão Network

Comment: OK, vou estudar mais um pouco e ver onde está o erro e posto novamente, muito obrigado pelo seu apoio

Comment: Agora aparece

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 683

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\gesind\application\models\Gesind_model.php
Line: 80
Function: where

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\gesind\application\controllers\Gesind.php
Line: 121
Function: pesquisa_matricula

Comment: e agora está chegando ate o model

Comment: No model, mude o retorno para $query->result() e veja oq acontece

Comment: Bom dia Phelipe, continua com o mesmo erro.
$this->db->where('matricula',$usr);
  var_dump($usr);
  echo "aqui";
  die();
  $query=$this->db->get("matriculas");
  if($query->num_rows()>0)
  {
   return $query->result();

  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
Resultado:
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 683</p>
<p>Backtrace:</p>
 
</div>array(1) {
  ["matricula"]=>
  string(6) "127898"
}
aqui

Comment: Se possível faça o seguinte, atualize os arquivo da publicação pq vou rodar na minha máquina e identificar o problema.

Comment: Atualizei, vou dar uma pesquisada tambem e obrigado por sua ajuda Phelipe

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta. Criei um banco de dados e fiz o teste e está funcionando perfeitamente. Se tiver algum problema comenta ai

Comment: Caracas irmão funcionou certinho, muito mas muito obrigado mesmo